# Deploying Sharepoint 2010 Webpart crashes Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I just installed Sharepoint 2010 stand-alone on Windows 7 and I'm trying to deploy a web part by simply selecting Build->Deploy. The web part doesn't contain anything; I just wanted to test if I can at least deploy an empty one.

Here's the output I get before Visual Studio crashes with "Visual Studio has encountered a problem and needs to close":

> ------ Deploy started: Project: SharePointProject3, Configuration:
>   Debug Any CPU ------ Active Deployment
>   Configuration: Default
>
> Run Pre-Deployment Command:   Skipping
>   deployment step because a
>   pre-deployment command is not
>   specified.
>
> Recycle IIS Application Pool:
>   Skipping application pool recycle
>   because no matching package on the
>   server was found.
>
> Retract Solution:   Skipping package
>   retraction because no matching package
>   on the server was found. Add Solution:

This is the entry in the application log:

> Application: devenv.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
>   Stack:
>      at EnvDTE.ProjectItem.get_Properties()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.ProjectUtils.GetFullPath(EnvDTE.ProjectItem)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.HierarchyItem.get_FullPath()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.ProjectMember.get_FullPath()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.ProjectExtensions.VSPackage.WebPartCommon.b__0(Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.ISharePointProjectItemFile)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.ProjectExtensions.VSPackage.ProjectItemTypeProvider.HasAnyFileChanged(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1)

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Are you running VS 2010 in Administrator mode ?

Comment: I wasn't, but I just tried and I get the same error.

Comment: Does your user have the correct rights in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling VS2010. Now it works.